# get file from subfolder in S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

To read a file stored directly in a S3 bucket, you use the following code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3.Bucket('mybucket').Object('example.txt').get()
file = s3_object['Body'].read()
```

However, the 'example.txt' file is stored in a sub-folder. How do I read in the file that is stored in 'mybucket/mysubfolder/example.txt'?

Comment: `.Object('mysubfolder/example.txt')`

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide the full key like this:

```
s3_object = s3.Bucket('mybucket').Object('mysubfolder/example.txt').get()
```

S3 is a key value pair storage the concept of folding is just for human readability.